# TestContainers GenericContainer start() never finishes

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kotlin, testcontainers

I'm using [TestContainers](https://java.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/) for some *acceptance-testing* in a kotlin spring-boot project.

I start all the docker containers successfully except a particular one, for which the `start()` method never finishes although (apparently) the container has started successfully.

I see it running both:

- In docker desktop and
- if I check it with docker ps in the terminal.

I have simplified to the extreme the configuration, startup strategies, etc. but the problem still remains.

Any idea of what can be happening?

```
GenericContainer("docker-image-identifier:latest")
            .withImagePullPolicy(PullPolicy.defaultPolicy())
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300))
            .withExposedPorts(38080, 8080)
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withEnv(
                mapOf(
                    "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE" to "local,mock"
                    // and some more env
                )
            )
```

Comment: how are you managing the container? Do you call start() and stop(), using try-with-resources? can you share a repository?

Comment: Just calling start(), which never finishes for that particular container. I will complete a little bit more the OP but I'm afraid I cannot share a repo as the docker image is internal and has confifentiality constraints. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez just check my answer if you are curious ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, the issue was that, for some reasons, one of the exposed ports(`38080`) was not responding. In this case, `TestContainers` `start()` keeps trying to establish connection with the port until the configured timeout happens.

This is the reason why `TestContainers` was considering that the container hadn't been started successfully.